# How i can get this using regular expressions?

Tags: regex

im working with regular expression and i cant get correct result.
I need to obtain the number preceded preceded by the word house.
Example:
I have:

FLOWERS 527 OFFICE 1217 **HOUSE *10***
ONE WAY 614 **HOUSE 4-C**
OTHER WAY 371 DEPARTMENT 209 **HOUSE *25 C***
SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 **HOUSE *3 C*** BLA BLA BLA

I am ise `(?<=\bCASA\s)\d+|\d+-\w\s\b` but I get to obtain just the number and lose the letter which may be written as follow:
**HOUSE *10*** just number
**HOUSE 4-C** number dash letter
 **HOUSE *25 C*** number space letter
**HOUSE *3 C*** BLA BLA BLA number space letter blablabla

What regular expression could use??

Comment: `HOUSE 3 C BLA BLA BLA` .. how do you know bla bla is not part of house number?

Comment: `HOUSE ([0-9]+)`  gets the number in the first capture group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?i)house\s+(\d+[-\s]?[a-zA-Z]?)\b
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/jP9tV2)

Comment: It might help to explain why this works instead of just giving it and asserting that it does.

Comment: @qaphla OP doesn't need explanation. As he said, he needs regex at the prior.

Comment: I friend, if i need extract all except HOUSE 4-C? Example: I have the address "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 HOUSE 3 C BLA BLA BLA", i'd like to extract "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 C BLA BLA BLA", without "HOUSE 3" ??

Answer (score 2):

This returns the number after the `HOUSE` and will catch also the next character:

```
/HOUSE (\d+[\s\-]?[A-Z]?)\b/
```

In the examples you gave, it will match:

- 10
- 4-C
- 25 C
- 3 C

Comment: I friend, if i need extract all except HOUSE 4-C? Example: I have the address "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 HOUSE 3 C BLA BLA BLA", i'd like to extract "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 C BLA BLA BLA", without "HOUSE 3" ??

Answer (score 2):

Try this : 
`(?<=\bHOUSE\s)(?:\d+-\w|\d+\s\w|\d+)\b`

NB. the order on a conditional statement is important, and the first successful match is taken, so if you have `\d+|\d+-\w` it will only match **4** in **4-C** but `\d+-\w|\d+` will match **4-C**

http://regex101.com/r/gS0aO6

Comment: Its exactly what i need. Tanks you very much! This solution try just what i need.

Comment: I friend, if i need extract all except HOUSE 4-C? Example: I have the address "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 HOUSE 3 C BLA BLA BLA", i'd like to extract "SAINT GEORGE 378 DEPARTMENT 808 C BLA BLA BLA", without "HOUSE 3" ??